# 検索時にキーボードが表示されない

Tags: ios, objective-c

UISearchBar を利用した検索を実装しています。
UISearchBar をタップしたときにソフトウェアキーボードを表示したいのですが表示されません。

どのようなコードを書けば表示されるのでしょうか。
下記は現在のコードです。

```
@interface SearchViewController ()

@property (nonatomic,strong) UISearchBar *searchBar;

@end

@implementation SearchViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]init];
    self.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
    self.searchBar.placeholder = @"検索";
    self.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.searchBar.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    [self.view addSubview:self.searchBar];
}
```

Comment: 上記コードで試したところ普通に出ました。もしかしてシミュレータですか？

Comment: はいその通りです。シミュレーターです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

本家の方に似たような事例がありました。
[Xcode 6: Keyboard does not show up in simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420873/xcode-6-keyboard-does-not-show-up-in-simulator)

シミュレーターのメニュー「Hardware」>「Keyboard」>「Connect Hardware Keyboard」のチェックをOFFにします。
するとシミュレータでキーボード入力するときにPCのリアルキーボードが使えなくなりますが、ソフトウェアキーボードは出るようになります。(多分...)

追記：  
私の経験則なのですが、「リアルキーボードも使いたい！」って場合は、シミュレータ上でソフトウェアキーボードが出ている時はリアルキーボードの「**英数**」「**かな**」切り替えキーに触らないように(押さないように)すると良さそうです。（ソフトウェアキーボードの方で切り替えるようにする）
それでもキーボードが消える場合は、シミュレータ上のアプリを一旦削除すると復活することがあります。

Comment: 出ました。ありがとうございます。